# Laptop will not stay in suspend

Tags: power-management, suspend, laptop, elementary-os

I have an Asus UX32VD, and it will not stay in suspend, but when I boot it from USB, it seems to be no problem at all.

Is there a clever way to check if it's something I have installed that wakes up the PC 2 seconds after it has been suspended? (I have suspected  mssql-server, but it happens even when I have that service stopped) I'm wondering if there's a log where I can read what exactly caused the wakeup.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this laptop has a combination BT WiFi chip, and as it turned out, it would suspend fine if the BT was turned off. Doing

```
sudo -s
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Solved it. I figure that's the 'wake on ethernet' that was disabled, but to the best of my knowledge it's nothing I've ever used.